# why is rand() generating a low number?

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
<?php

function random_id() {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $id = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i)
    {
        $id .= $chars[rand(1, 26)];
    }
    echo $id;
}

random_id();

?>
```

It keeps generating IDs with 5 lowercase digits, and VERY occasionally it will have a number in it. I tried with `mt_rand()` as well, and also using `srand(time())` and `srand(microtime())` at the beginning of the script before the loop.

Also, should it be `rand(1, 26)` or `rand(0, 25)`?

Comment: Have you actually counted the characters in `$chars`?

Comment: I cannot believe I made such a stupid mistake lol. Thank you everyone!

Comment: To avoid such mistakes in the future, consider [afpel’s solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14426984/53114).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your string is longer than 26 characters. Use this rand function instead:

```
rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)
```

So that you're not calculating string length on every iteration, but still keeping it dynamic, it is worth considering moving the calculation outside of the loop like so:

```
$chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$chars_cnt = strlen($chars) - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i)
{
    $id .= $chars[rand(1, $chars_cnt)];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not generating a random number that's high enough to get the entire array.

Lowercase chars: 0-25

Numbers: 26-35

Uppercase cars: 36-61

Answer (score 2):

`0` is the start point and `strlen($chars)` is the count of character in the `$str` string.
You should change your code to this:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i)
    {
        $id .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remember to use a bigger number than 26, as that is the number of letters in the alphabet, you might want to use 26+26+10= 62:

```
$id .= $chars[rand(0, 61)];
```

CHEERS!

Comment: PHP’s arrays are 0-based.

Comment: OOPS, I'm doing two things at once here.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in PHP are zero indexed, so yes the first number in the call should be zero. You're also only picking from the beginning of the array.

Use this in stead:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i)
{
    $id .= $chars[rand(0, 61];
}
```

Comment: `rand`’s limits are inclusive but array index `62` would be out of range.

Comment: Yea, it was a typo I was fixing while you commented

Answer (score 1):

Your $chars holds a string with length > 26 but your random number is between 1 and 26 (inclusive). The string index starts with 0 that is char a. For now only chars bcd...xyz1 are used. You could check the string-length dynamically and get a valid random number.

```
function random_id() { 
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 
    $chars_cnt = strlen($chars)-1; 
    $id = ''; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) 
    {   
        $id .= $chars[rand(0, $chars_cnt)]; 
    } 
    return $id; 
} 

echo random_id();
```